# How to add an indicator column for concat in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

With `merge()` there is an indicator parameter so you can identify from which df you the original data is found. I don't see a similar function with`concat()`.

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, indicator=True)
```

Is there a way to create an indicator column with `concat()`?

Comment: index the the key for concat, just set_index() with the indicator

Comment: Would you mind showing an example so I can give you credit for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up creating a new column labeled `FileName` in each file, then I `concat()`.

```
df1['FileName'] = 'df1'
df2['FileName'] = 'df2'


final = pd.concat(df1,df2)

Column1   Column2   Column3  FileName
3         89        08       df1
43        934       34       df1
34        934       32       df2
431       2342      23       df2
```

Answer (score 13):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(['a','b'], index=[0,1], columns=['letter'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['c','d','e'], index=[2,3,4], columns=['letter'])
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, keys=['from_df1','from_df2']).reset_index(level=[0])
```

df1

```
  letter
0      a
1      b
```

df2

```
  letter
2      c
3      d
4      e
```

result

```
    level_0 letter
0  from_df1      a
1  from_df1      b
2  from_df2      c
3  from_df2      d
4  from_df2      e
```

Comment: Add `names=['source']` to the `concat` function to name the column